# Xcode - Bitcode error only when running on device

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode

When running my app on simulator, it works perfectly, but when I try to run it on my device, I get the following error:

> '/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-dvsqmvczxjaaajfxojqecerjuauk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Amplitude-iOS/Amplitude_iOS.framework/Amplitude_iOS'
> does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
> (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
> vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file
> '/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-dvsqmvczxjaaajfxojqecerjuauk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Amplitude-iOS/Amplitude_iOS.framework/Amplitude_iOS'
> for architecture arm64

In both PROJECT and TARGET, I have changed the Enable Bitcode to Yes, inside the Build Options. I have also tried restarting my Mac and iPhone 14. I have also deleted everything in the Derived Data folder multiple times.

Any other ideas what might be the reason?

Comment: Setting Enable Bitcode to NO should fix it

Comment: @ArikSegal Does it matter for my app if I use NO instead of YES? Will I notice any changes?

Comment: No you won't. BitCode support has been announced deprecated by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by selecting pods and then bitcode to YES just like this.

[image: Bit code with pods]

Comment: For me not working both Yes and No :(

Comment: first set bitcode yes for pods and then unity-iphone set bitcode for No.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting Enable Bitcode to No.

Comment: For me not working both Yes and No :(